# Problem with input inside input and @

Tags: macros, packages, input

I'm working in a package and want to create libraries, such as `tikz` and its `usetikzlibrary`.

However, as I use `@` in private macro names, when a library uses another I get an error.

Here's my MWE (description below):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}

% hack to make filecontents overwrite
\makeatletter
\let\oldfilec@ntents\filec@ntents
\gdef\filec@ntents{\filec@ntents@overwrite\oldfilec@ntents}
\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{libraryone.tex}
    \def\@libonevar{lib 1 variable with @}
    \def\libonefunction{\@libonevar}
    \def\libonevar{lib 1 variable without @}
    \def\liboneotherfunction{\libonevar}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{librarytwo.tex}
    \loadlibrary{libraryone}
    \def\@libtwovar{lib 2 variable}
    \def\libtwofunction{\libonefunction}
    \def\libtwootherfunction{\liboneotherfunction}
\end{filecontents}
    

\begin{filecontents}{mypackage.sty}
    \def\@pkgvar{pkg variable}
    \def\pkgfuncion{\@pkgvar}
    \newcommand{\loadlibrary}[1]{
        \input{#1}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{mypackage}

\begin{document}
From package: \pkgfuncion

\loadlibrary{libraryone}
From library one: \libonefunction\ and \liboneotherfunction

\loadlibrary{librarytwo}
From library one: \libonefunction\ and \liboneotherfunction % \libonefunction fails!

\end{document}
```

If I load `libraryone`, I'm able to use both `\libonefunction` and `liboneotherfunction`. However, if I load `librarytwo`, which loads `libraryone`, `\liboneotherfunctions` stops working with a message like "*Use of @ doesn't match its definition. From library one: \libonefunction*." `\liboneotherfunction` keeps working just fine.

If I remove all `@` the problem goes away, for now, I really prefer to keep using `@` for private stuff.

I read articles like [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) but I found nothing about problems with macro names with `@` in them.

Is there a way to avoid this problem?

**EDIT**

My problem remains even after @egreg's and @Ulrich Diez answers.

This is my current actual code (which uses TeX primitives since I thought `\IfFileExists` could be another problem):

```
% usedslibrary: load libraries
\newcommand{\ds@loadlibrary}[1]{%
    \ifcsname ds@library#1loaded\endcsname%
        %\PackageWarning{dsdraw}{Library '#1' already loaded.}%
    \else%
        \openin15={#1.code.tex}%
        \ifeof15%
            \PackageWarning{dsdraw}{Couldn't find any library named '#1'.}%
        \else%
            \closein15%
            \makeatletter%
            \input{#1.code.tex}%
            %\makeatother%
            \expandafter\def\csname ds@library#1loaded\endcsname{defined}%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just nest the `\input`-command between `\makeatletter`..`\makeatother`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}


\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite,nosearch]{libraryone.tex}
\def\@libonevar{lib 1 variable with @}%
\def\libonefunction{\@libonevar}%
\def\libonevar{lib 1 variable without @}%
\def\liboneotherfunction{\libonevar}%
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite,nosearch]{librarytwo.tex}
\loadlibrary{libraryone}%
\def\@libtwovar{lib 2 variable}%
\def\libtwofunction{\libonefunction}%
\def\libtwootherfunction{\liboneotherfunction}%
\end{filecontents*}
    

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite,nosearch]{mypackage.sty}
\def\@pkgvar{pkg variable}%
\def\pkgfuncion{\@pkgvar}%
\newcommand{\loadlibrary}[1]{%
   \makeatletter\input{#1}\makeatother %<-------
}%
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{mypackage}

\begin{document}
From package: \pkgfuncion

\loadlibrary{libraryone}
From library one: \libonefunction\ and \liboneotherfunction

\loadlibrary{librarytwo}
From library one: \libtwofunction\ and \libtwootherfunction

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When TeX processes `\usepackage{mypackage}` it will, among other things, do `\makeatletter` and then `\input{mypackage.sty}`.

This does *not* happen with `\input`. Since `\loadlibrary{libraryone}` just does `\input{libraryone}`, TeX will interpret the first instruction

```
\def\@libonevar{lib 1 variable with @}
```

as the definition for the control symbol `\@`. This definition *requires* that `\@` is followed by `libonevar`. Next `\libonefunction` is defined to expand to `\@libonevar`.

When you do also `\loadlibrary{librarytwo}`, `\@` gets a different definition and now it requires that `libtwovar` follows it. When you now try  `\libonefunction`, TeX substitutes it with `\@libonevar` and wants to expand `\@`, which is followed by the wrong tokens.

Solution: if your library files want to define command names with `@` in them, do

```
\newcommand{\loadlibrary}[1]{%
  \makeatletter
  \input{#1}%
  \makeatother
}
```

By the way, the hack to make `filecontents` overwrite is no longer necessary; just call

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{<filename>}
```

Full example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{libraryone.tex}
\def\@libonevar{lib 1 variable with @}
\def\libonefunction{\@libonevar}
\def\libonevar{lib 1 variable without @}
\def\liboneotherfunction{\libonevar}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{librarytwo.tex}
\loadlibrary{libraryone}
\def\@libtwovar{lib 2 variable}
\def\libtwofunction{\libonefunction}
\def\libtwootherfunction{\liboneotherfunction}
\end{filecontents}
    

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
\def\@pkgvar{pkg variable}
\def\pkgfuncion{\@pkgvar}
\newcommand{\loadlibrary}[1]{%
    \makeatletter
    \input{#1}%
    \makeatother
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{mypackage}

\begin{document}
From package: \pkgfuncion

\loadlibrary{libraryone}
From library one: \libonefunction\ and \liboneotherfunction

\loadlibrary{librarytwo}
From library one: \libonefunction\ and \liboneotherfunction % \libonefunction fails!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me it seems a little odd that `\input` keeps the package's intrinsic `\makeatletter` when `\loadlibrary` is called from `.sty` and forgets about it inside the library source... That makes sense though. Thanks for the `overwrite` option, since I learned only yesterday the package `filecontents` was deprecated and I didn't bother finding more about it.

Comment: Actually I had to remove the `\makeatother` that follows `\input`, since it was changing the `@` catcode back and all private definitions after `\loadlibrary` went wrong. I side effect is that I guess it will left `makeatletter` active even for the main document. I will make a version to check where the library is been called from... maybe a starred or private version `\@loadlibrary`...

Comment: @Jander I believe you're using the wrong approach. You ***don't*** want that `\makeatletter` holds in the whole document.

Comment: I don't really want that, @egreg! :-)    I edited the question with my actual current code. Maybe there's something there I'm missing. And, of course, I'll have to handle the `\makeatother` issue...